# How to select nodes in Netbeans Visual Library?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I create a graph based visual applicaion using a Netbens Visual Library.

Can somebody post a code sample that enables a selection of nodes with mouse clicks (and Ctrl key fo multiple selection) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://graph.netbeans.org/examples.html contains many well written examples. Don't miss **test.action.SelectLockedActionTest**!

Answer (score 0):

same link, but `test.object.MultiMoveActionTest` is a more relevant example.